# Неучитываемые - причастие или отглагольное прилагательное?

Tags: пунктуация

За пределами расширяющихся кругов влияния все новых факторов, создающих основу для повышения доли неопределенности в прогнозировании курса, стоит невидное и неподконтрольное любой модели множество факторов экономического, политического, социального и технологического характера и сильные, неучитываемые до сих пор факторы национального и религиозного характера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К прилагательным относятся слова, образованные от непереходных глаголов: ***невредимый, невысыхаемый, независимый, незначимый*** или от глаголов совершенного вида ***(причастия нa мый от глаголов совершенного вида не образуются): невыполнимый (от выполнить — сов. в.), неистощимый (истощить), неисчислимый (исчислить).***

В вашем примере слово "учесть" является глаголом совершенного вида (хотя и переходным). Поэтому - прилагательное.

Comment: Соответственно пишется слитно? А нужна ли перед ним запятая?

Comment: Да, слова на мый подчиняются правилам написания не с прилагательными и с причастиями.Подробнее здесь:[Правописание частиц НЕ и НИ. НЕ с именами прилагательными](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53)

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: учитываемые - от учитывать - несов. вида и переходный, зависимые слова ДО СИХ ПОР не стоят в творительном падеже, потому и  прилагательное и пишется с НЕ слитно.

Comment: Не вижу комментарий Людмилы. Хотя на почту пришло сообщение об ответе Людмилы. Странно...

Comment: Переделала в комментарий, потому что отвлеклась и опоздала с ответом, зачем же ещё один ответ?

Comment: Людмила, есть глагол "учесть'' - именно он указан в словаре. Надо учитывать его. Ср.: неистощимый (истощить). Можно и образовать и несовершенный вид: истощать. Но в словаре - истощить,  поэтому - совершенный вид. невидимые - (может быть причастием и прилагательным. Образован от глагола "видеть" несовершенный вид.

Comment: В словаре исходный глагол, но от него образуется причастие учтённый, а вот учитываемый - от учитывать. Цепочка: учесть - учитывать(черед. е-и, с-т) -учитываемый. По правилам словообразования причастие настоящего времени образуются от основы глаголов настоящего времени, а от основы инфинитива только формы прошедшего времени - действ. и страд. прич. и дееприч. сов вида. У нас же  страдат.прич. наст. времени, значит, образовано  никак не от основы инфинитива, а от основы глагола наст. времени, т.е. учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

> (причастия нa -мый от глаголов совершенного вида не образуются): невыполнимый (от выполнить — сов. в.)

Или я к концу рабочего дня плохо соображаю, или здесь нет логики между утверждением и примером. Помогите!

Comment: Инна, а что вас смущает? Невыполнимый - это отглагольное прилагательное.

Comment: Да. А __не учитываемый__ - причастие. Вот это и смущает (уже третьего человека в этой теме).

Comment: Вот-вот. Как же быть с определением причастия в школе?